# How can I add a key/value pair to a Javascript object when the value is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to add a new key to my Javascript object, obj.  Using the method below works fine as long as I have a value to go with the key.

The method below inserts the actual characters "" into the value position.  I want to add the new item "key3", but I want it to now appear in obj as "key3":{} .

Here is my code:

```js
    //1.adding key/value pair
    var obj ={
        "key1":{},
        "key2":{}
    };
    obj["key3"] = "test";

    //obj now looks like:
    obj ={
        "key1":{},
        "key2":{},
        "key3": test
    };

    //2.adding key/value pair with empty value
    var obj ={
        "key1":{},
        "key2":{}
    };
    obj["key3"] = "";

    //obj now looks like:
    obj ={
        "key1":{},
        "key2":{},
        "key3": ""
    };

    //but I want obj to look like:
    var obj ={
        "key1":{},
        "key2":{},
        "key3":{}
    };
```

Comment: Why not just assign an empty object literal `{}` instead of an empty string?

Comment: I find it difficult to understand your problem, but you can assign an empty object a la `obj["key3"] = {};`. To add a key, you must have a value. Even if that value is undefined. `obj["key3"] = undefined;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assign an object instead of a string.

```
var obj ={
    "key1":{},
    "key2":{}
};



obj["key3"] = {};



//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
New Object:

var obj ={
    "key1":{},
    "key2":{},
    "key3":{}
};
```

Answer (score 1):

A functional, non-mutative approach with ES6 could look something like this:

```
const initialObject = {
    key1:{},
    key2:{}
};

const keysToAdd = {
  key3: {}
};

const updatedObject = Object.assign({}, initialObject, keysToAdd);

console.log(updatedObject);
```

[JS Bin Example](http://jsbin.com/sidezarezo/edit?js,console)